Why doesn't UI Check Mode show all cases?
Android compose has a beautiful functionality called UI check mode allowing to find out fast if your app has any issues on other screen sizes. But for some reason after pressing Start UI Check Mode button i don't see all cases. Android Studio shows me only a few. For example like this:

As you can see it shows me only 2 cases. Why? How can i see all ?

The reason is because UI check mode only shows all the configurations with problems.
Source: https://www.droidcon.com/2024/03/22/accessibility-checks-with-jetpack-compose-previews/#:~:text=The%20accessibility%20checks%20the%20UI,size%2C%20and%20low%20contrast%20categories.
